# How can I delimiter separated words into an array with key being left part from delimiter and value the right part

Tags: php, database, encoding

I have a string like this, where each word is marked with encoding (`FW`, `PRP`, etc) using underline:

```
Hi_FW !_.
My_PRP$ name_NN 's_POS Jim_NNP ._.
I_PRP 'm_VBP from_IN New_NNP Zealand_NNP ._.
This_DT is_VBZ my_PRP$ friend_NN ._.
His_PRP$ name_NN 's_POS Adam_NNP ._.
He_PRP 's_VBZ from_IN Australia_NNP ._.
This_DT is_VBZ my_PRP$ friend_NN too_RB ._.
Her_PRP$ name_NN 's_POS Paola_NNP ._.
She_PRP 's_VBZ from_IN Italy_NNP ._.
```

I need to break it into an array where a key is a word, and its value is its corresponding tag:

```
[
    "Hi" => "FW",
    "My" => "PRP$",
    "name" => "NN"
    ...
]
```

I assume I can somehow split this string by the delimiter `_`, but can't seem to find a good way to then join it into the array I need.

How can that be achieved?

Comment: My PHP's a little rusty. Would it not be easier to split on spaces first and then splitting each element on ``_``?

Comment: Do you need ._. these also or want to remove from array

Comment: @SunilPachlangia, no, these should be removed from array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = explode("\n", $string);
$newarr = array();
foreach($arr as $item)
{
    $explodeditem = explode(' ', $item);
    foreach($explodeditem as $string)
        array_push ($newarr, $string);
}
$result = array();
foreach($newarr as $item)
{
    $newArr = explode('_', $item);
    $result[$newArr[0]] = $newArr[1];
}
```

Comment: Please check I've added `$result = array();`.

Comment: Did you checked my link

Comment: Yes. `unexpected '$result'` means `$result` is not declared as array. Sorry I missed.

Comment: Typo! You were missing semicolon **;** `explode('_', $item)` <-- over here. Even though it doesn't result the output as expected

Comment: Please see I've updated my asnwer. It gives the result as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume we are reading from a file (data.txt) then the following reads the contents of the file using [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) which can be omitted if your requirement is a string.

The following is a **partial naive implementation solution** intended to give you a head start. Comments for given very simple delimiters and use of multiple [preg_split()](http://php.net/preg-split) (twice):

```
<?php

$results = array();
$delimiter = '_';

$file_handle = fopen("data.txt", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {

   // ie. My_PRP$ name_NN 's_POS Jim_NNP ._.
   $line = fgets($file_handle);

   // validations ommited 

   // split by delimiter '_'
   // [0] = My
   // [1] = PRP$
   $line_array = preg_split("/$delimiter/", $line);

   // ie. for cases Hi_FW !_.
   // from results above, split by space
   // [0] = FW
   // [1] = !
   $value = preg_split("/\s/", $line_array[1]);

   // sighh, adding delimiter back to key-value array
   $result[$line_array[0]] = $delimiter.$value[0];
}
fclose($file_handle);

print_r($result);

?>
```

**data.txt**

```
Hi_FW !_.
My_PRP$ name_NN 's_POS Jim_NNP ._.
I_PRP 'm_VBP from_IN New_NNP Zealand_NNP ._.
This_DT is_VBZ my_PRP$ friend_NN ._.
His_PRP$ name_NN 's_POS Adam_NNP ._.
He_PRP 's_VBZ from_IN Australia_NNP ._.
This_DT is_VBZ my_PRP$ friend_NN too_RB ._.
Her_PRP$ name_NN 's_POS Paola_NNP ._.
She_PRP 's_VBZ from_IN Italy_NNP ._.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would do an explode on whitespaces and than on `_`

```
<?php
$inputArray = explode(" ", $input);

$sentences = array();

foreach ($inputArray as $word){
    $wordArray = explode("_", $word);
    $sentences[$wordArray[0]] = $wordArray[1];
}
```